# How do you configure the spring integration poller after XSD changes have invalidated the fixed-delay and fixed-rate attributes?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

**Original xml:**

```
<int:poller default="true" task-executor="stepTaskExecutor" fixed-delay="1000">
```

The fixed-delay attribute is no longer legal, and fails XML parsing in the (eclipse) IDE.

**Alternative configuration:**
An alternative suggested elsewhere (including https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/2.0.0.M3/spring-integration-reference/html/samples.html):

```
<!-- Globally scoped Spring Integration bean resources -->
<!-- see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73450768/how-to-configure-channels-and-amq-for-spring-batch-integration-where-all-steps-a/73455134#73455134 -->
<!-- see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28625635/attribute-fixed-rate-is-not-allowed-to-appear-in-element-intpoller -->
<int:poller default="true" task-executor="stepTaskExecutor">
    <int:interval-trigger interval="1000"/>
</int:poller>
```

This passes the XML parsing in the IDE, but fails at runtime

**Log snip:**

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'int:interval-trigger'. One of '{"http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration":transactional, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration":advice-chain}' is expected.
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator$XSIErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.reportSchemaError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNamespaceBinder.handleStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNamespaceBinder.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DTDConfiguration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DTDConfiguration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:77)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadDocument(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:432)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
    ... 50 common frames omitted
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Spring Tool Suite (eclipse), or add the spring tools plugin to your eclipse so that the schema is loaded from the jar file instead of from the internet.

https://spring.io/tools

Comment: I figured it out - updating my POM's to 6.0.0 (and doing a ton of refactoring)